# Full Screen Swing with JOGL

Tags: java, swing, opengl, graphics, jogl

I am trying to make a Swing application which renders in full screen, following the description here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html and the source code here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/example-1dot4/DisplayModeTest.java

This works quite well, however as soon as I drop in a GLCanvas object as one of the components of the frame, all that shows up is a black screen.  Exiting full screen, I can see the OpenGL image for a moment at full screen, then it shows up fine again in a window.  Even though nothing is being displayed, I can interact with the swing components, like buttons, as if they were.

It seems to me almost like another blank buffer is being drawn above the actual swing app, but I can't figure out why that would be.  Alternatively, I wonder if it's not an issue with the full screen being handled by the graphics card which is also handling JOGL?

I don't *need* the hardware accelerated full screen, though it might be nice - if this is unresolvable, is there some more robust way to implement full screen in a Java app?

Comment: OS?  OpenGL implementation vendor?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed (silly of me) that this would be platform independent.  I'm running Windows 7 with a Nvidia GForce 9600M GT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true` as [this FAQ](http://opengl.j3d.org/faq/jogl_basics.html#fullscreen) says.

Comment: Thank you, that worked flawlessly. Now I have to go figure out the best way to force this command line argument to be included every time it's run.

Comment: Test by setting `System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");`

Comment: Glorious, thank you.  /Now/ I just need to figure out how to enable and disable the frame decoration (`setUndecorated()`?) after the frame has been displayed.  I'll go ask/look for this myself, unless you wanna help me out some more? :P

Comment: Yepp! :) `frame.setUndecorated(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call setUndecorated(...) on a displayable window, you have to dispose it first but this will dispose the canvas too. Use a shared drawable to do this and remove it before calling dispose() on the frame.

Comment: Yes, I have run into that problem.  It's fortunately only a minor inconvenience for my application, but I'd still like to get it working properly.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "Use a shared drawable to do this and remove it"?

Comment: I faced the same problem. If you use only a shared context, when you remove a canvas from a window, this context will be destroyed except if you use NEWT instead of AWT/Swing. You can see an example of shared drawables there: http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl.git;a=blob;f=src/junit/com/jogamp/test/junit/jogl/acore/TestSharedContextListAWT.java;h=b44158dce98537b7e12e4a354a702d0082f2b4ef;hb=de2a30104098216963132ed02b3dd66acd799d9e#l65

Comment: I discovered the actual cause of the problem I was running into was some run-once setup code that was in init() of the OpenGL panel.  Since init() get's called again when redisplaying the panel, it was re-running it.  By moving the run-once code to the constructor, I resolved the problems I was seeing, and it now works perfectly :D