# Undecorated full-screen JFrame showing JPanel doesn't repaint until Alt-tab

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jogl

I have a JPanel v. Function below creates a full-screen Jframe, called window, which will feature this JPanel. I have:

```
protected final void fullScreenMulti(final JPanel v)  {
    final JFrame window= new JFrame();
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.add(v);
    //window.setVisible(true);
    .
    .
    .
    window.validate();
    window.repaint();
    GraphicsDevice gdev = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gdev.setFullScreenWindow(window);

    DisplayMode mode = gdev.getDisplayMode();
    window.setSize(mode.getWidth(), mode.getHeight());
}
```

This works for the default render that is written for the code. However, selecting the GL renderer which uses JOGL, makes the fullscreen frame blank and I get a white screen. You will have to switch-tab in and out, or press Start for the Panel to be painted. I tried changing the background of *window* using:

```
Container c = window.getContentPane();
c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
```

that doesn't do anything though and I still get a white screen. (Although when i debug, I can see that the background property is successfully applied.)

Also clicking on the blank area of a second screen(The window is hosted on the first screen), or even clicking the Start button, SOMETIMES makes the frame go Black and my mouse adaptor fails to work afterwards. (what exactly could be happenning here, how can I investigate it?) Other times, it has the same effect of Alt-tab.

Haven't done much Swing stuff in Java and a I'm bit lost. Seeing that it seems to be working fine on one renderer and not on the other, suggests that it has something to do with the GL renderer, but the renderer works fine when rendering JPanels in my non-full screen mode; Also my understanding is that the role of the renderers is merely to buffer the video that is featured on my JPanel.(I mean that's what renderers do, right?) so it is probably a case of some setting not being specified above, but the original renderer takes care of it. Any suggestions what that might be?

edit: needless to say, taking out window.add(v) will make the frame render fine and the result of changing frame background etc. that was previously not working, will now be visible on the frame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Thanks, but this is a massive project. I have added the bit I found to be relevant. I await an initial diagnosis to supply the other bits. isn't that what you're supposed to do?

Comment: *"I have added the bit I found to be relevant"*  Prove it's relevant by calling it from a `main(String[)` to show the problem on-screen.  Otherwise I (and perhaps others) would be skeptical of your analysis that the relevant code *is* shown.

Comment: Have you tried calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on the `JPanel` AFTER it's made full screen...

Comment: @AndrewThompson The project is pretty modular, all the other bits are individually tested. Also, it works fine with one particular setting as stated. The same panel is also displayed fine in the non-screen mode. I remain confident in my analysis, but would be open to suggestions as to what I might be missing here.

Comment: @MadProgrammer By panel you mean frame? I just added 
window.validate();
window.repaint();
after 
window.setSize(mode.getWidth(), mode.getHeight()); but that didn't do anything. don't have revalidate() as an option.

Comment: @MadProgrammer the said JPanel isn't actually owned by any other frame. but I tried v.revalidate();
        v.repaint(); both after setSize() and .add(). that too did nothing.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Feel free to mark this question as duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245060/full-screen-swing-with-jogl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [problem](http://opengl.j3d.org/faq/jogl_basics.html#fullscreen). *-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true* solves it.